# Find by how much SKSpriteNodes overlap

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

I am trying to do overlap checking in my SpriteKit game and I would like to know how much the overlap is when two sprites overlap. Here is my code to do the check:

```
- (BOOL)checkNodeLocation:(SKSpriteNode *)node
{
    for (SKSpriteNode *arrayNode in self.nodeArray)
    {
        if ([node intersectsNode:arrayNode])
        {
            NSLog(@"They MATCH!");
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"THEY DON'T");
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This seems to work, but the problem again is I don't know which way to move the node. How can I find out the overlap amount?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific command for what you're looking for. You can try using the the positions of both sprites, taking into account each sprites frame, to calculate the degree of overlap.

Comment: use CGRectIntersection() with the frame of each sprite (frame of a sprite is CGRectMake(position.x,position.y,size.width,size.height))